# Why are my Vue components invisible? (Single File Component)

Tags: webpack, vue-component

[Code here](https://github.com/write-io/write.io/tree/single-file-components)

I'm trying to build a [Vue Single File Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html). After going through some hurdles with Webpack, I finally got to a stage where I see no errors nor warnings, and my bundle.js seems to contain all the code.

Now, everything on the page is invisible.

My HTML lies inside `game.vue` and `home.vue` inside `<template>`. Why isn't it showing?

Answer (score 0):

In my main app.vue, I was missing the placemenet of the two other vues:

**app.vue**

```
<div id="app">
    <home></home>
    <game></game>
</div>
```

**home.vue**

...

**game.vue**

...